# How to modify Access DB File which is in sharepoint Document Library

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, document-library

I am having accdb file(Ms access DB file) in sharepoint Document Library. I want edit the file in browser or without downloading the file to the local.

I am able to view the file but not able to Edit it.

Need help

Answer (score 0):

Access doesn’t really work this way. You can store the data tables in Sharepoint, but you still need the local access file to interact with it. You can link to data tables in Sharepoint. Instead of creating a brand new table, you import the data source.

Microsoft does have a newish program out now called PowerApps that may help you accomplish something closer to what you’re describing.